# Wrong dual monitor settings upon second user login

Tags: resolution, multiple-monitors, multi-user

This is a problem that is present since several years. Scanning the net for solutions you find a many threads, but mostly with not feasible solutions. I think it is a main issue, that is not recognized as such. And even if a ask the question for Kubuntu it seams to be a problem also in Ubuntu, since I found several threads on both Ubuntu and Kubuntu dealing with this same issue.

This is the issue:
- Under what circumstances: A PC, Laptop or Virtual Machine (all of them).
- Hardware: a system with two monitors with unequal resolutions; both with main monitor having higher of lower resolution
- When: when logging in into two different user accounts

- What works fine: any first logging (after a start of the system) in into an account works fine; both monitors configure automatically to the proper resolution, positions and mirroring mode are set correctly, according to last saved settings. Any account behaves correctly if it is the first to have logged in.
- After such a first logging, I change user and log in on a different account. So there are two accounts opened at the same time now.
- The problem:
       very often, but not always after opening a second account
       the resolution, monitor position, and/or mirroring mode are screwed up.
       Trying to fix it with  setting -> display and monitor is not possible, having                         no effect to the real screen: changing configuration in the dialog                 does has no effect on the reality
- Even after changing the configuration through the display dialog,
  does not change the reality: the two screens stay one on top of the other
- Errors that occur upon logging in as a second user are are different depending on the hardware running on: monitors displaying on top of one another, highest resolution selectable is lower than what the monitor can do (happens mostly on Virtualbox Virtual Machine)

The strange thing is: that the first log in always works fine. The second log in mostly leads to problems on all machines, and on virtual machines as well.

Could you suggest me a work around?
And would you file this problem to fix it in future editions of Ubuntu?